# Mvc login page using linq and entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a login page which takes the password and matches with the passwords stored in database and these passwords are stored in plane texts. In the same table i have another column which has all the passwords in encrypted form "SHA512". So what i really want to do is to match the user input password with the encrypted passwords and do the login operation.

```
` public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(CustomerCallerList c)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (AdcoDBEntities AdcoDB = new AdcoDBEntities())
            {
                var v = AdcoDB.CustomerCallerLists.Where(a => a.Name.Equals(c.Name) && a.Password.Equals(c.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (v != null)
                {
                    Session["LoginID"] = v.ID.ToString();
                    Session["LoginUser"] = v.Name.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("AfterLogin");
                }
            }
        }
        return View(c);
    }`
```

This is my controller for matching it with plane text passwords.

My view looks like this

```
`@model MvcWebSite.Models.CustomerCallerList

 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
  }

<h2>Login</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login","Home",FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken() //this is for prevent CSRF attack
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  if (@ViewBag.Message != null)
 { 
 <div>
    @ViewBag.Message
 </div>
}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(a=>a.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=>a.Name)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(a=>a.Password)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.Password)</td>
        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=>a.Password)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
 @section Scripts{
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 }'
```

This is the changed code for matching with encryption column

```
` public ActionResult Login(CustomerCallerList c)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (AdcoDBEntities AdcoDB = new AdcoDBEntities())
            {
                var passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c.PasswordSHA);
                byte[] hashBytes;
                using (var sha = new SHA512Managed())
                {
                    hashBytes = sha.ComputeHash(passwordBytes);
                }
                var sb = new StringBuilder(hashBytes.Length * 2);
                foreach (var b in hashBytes)
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
                var hashStr = sb.ToString();
                var v = AdcoDB.CustomerCallerLists.Where(a => a.Name.Equals(c.Name) && a.Password.Equals(hashStr)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (v != null)
                {
                    Session["LoginID"] = v.ID.ToString();
                    Session["LoginUser"] = v.Name.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("AfterLogin");
                }
            }
        }
        return View(c);
    }`
```

Comment: You don't want to reinvent the wheel when it comes to security. Use ASP.NET Identity for user management, authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code the compute the SHA512 hash of the password:

```
var passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c.password);
byte[] hashBytes;
using (var sha = new SHA512Managed()) {
  hashBytes = sha.ComputeHash(passwordBytes);
}
```

If your encrypted password is stored as hex string, use the following code to convert `hashBytes` to string:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(hashBytes.Length * 2);
foreach (var b in hashBytes)
  sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
var hashStr = sb.ToString();
```

Then you can match either `hashBytes` or `hashStr` to your encrypted password column, by replacing `a.Password.Equals(c.Password)` with something appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, but it is giving me an error saying "String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: s"

Comment: var passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c.PasswordSHA);This line

Comment: Apparently `c.PasswordSHA` is `null`. Perhaps it should be `c.Password` instead?

Comment: Please see the question i have updated with the new code given by you , see where i am making mistake. Actually i am a student learning by myself  so don't have much idea about MVC.

Comment: And PasswordSHA is the column which has all the passwords in encrypted form. Password contains plain text.

Comment: OK, in the `Login` method, `c.Password` contains the plain text password given by the user, and you want to compute its SHA512 hash, so you should write `GetBytes(c.Password)`. After the computation, `hashStr` contains the SHA512 hash in string form, something like "b109f3....cbc86" (128 characters long). Then you should match it against the records in the database, i.e. `a => a.Name.Equals(c.Name) && a.PasswordSHA.Equals(hashStr)`.

Comment: No actually c.Password contains all the plane text passwords stored in database.Please see the view.Thank you

Comment: Now i am able to get the particular encrypted password as per the name, can you share the code for decoding it so i can match it with the user input password. Thanks

Comment: No, SHA is a one-way function, you can't decode it. Check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm.